# noUiSlider noUi-connect background image offset

Tags: css, nouislider

In noUiSlider 10, I was able to create a "groove" background image fpr the .noUi-connect class using gradients, and position it so that the ends of the "groove" did not extend into the rounded edges of the slider background.

[image: noUiSlider 11 .noUi-connect styling]

In noUiSlider 13, I am no longer able to keep the "groove" out of the end cap.
[image: noUiSlider 13 .noU-connect styling]

I've tried the same CSS, but the background-position: left 5px center; trick no longer seems to work.

Manipulating the .noUi-target class background still works, in that I can shrink the background size by 10px, and then move it over to keep the "groove" out of the end caps.

Comment: Could you add your CSS (preferably in a running example?

Comment: @Lg102, I apologize, it was with 10.0.0 where the groove trick worked. Here's a pen [link](https://codepen.io/mdeggers/pen/pGLdXr). With 13.1.0, the same trick does not work - see [link](https://codepen.io/mdeggers/pen/pGLpEp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly resize the `noUi-connects` element to achieve this effect:

```
.noUi-connects {
    margin: 0 3px;
    width: calc(100% - 6px); /* 2 * 3px */
}
```

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/leongersen/pen/vbRbLx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!